# Can AccessibilityService perform click event on Background App without opening the app

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

From my MainActivity I'm using AccessibilityService to perform click event on another app and it works when I open the app and it is displayed on the screen. However I want to perform the click event without having to open the app, it can be opened but not currently displayed on the screen.

Is this possible?

```
public class DiaryAppAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {


@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent (AccessibilityEvent event) {


    if (getRootInActiveWindow () == null) {
        return;
    }

    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat rootInActiveWindow = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.wrap (getRootInActiveWindow());

    List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> messageNodeList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId ("com.diaryapp:id/entry");
    if (messageNodeList == null || messageNodeList.isEmpty ()) {
        return;
    }

    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat messageField = messageNodeList.get (0);

    if (messageField.getText () == null || messageField.getText ().length () == 0
            || !messageField.getText ().toString ().endsWith (getApplicationContext ().getString (R.string.diaryapp_suffix))) { // So your service doesn't process any message, but the ones ending your apps suffix
        return;
    }

    List<AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat> sendMessageNodeInfoList = rootInActiveWindow.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId ("com.diaryapp:id/send");
    if (sendMessageNodeInfoList == null || sendMessageNodeInfoList.isEmpty ()) {
        return;
    }

    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat sendMessageButton = sendMessageNodeInfoList.get (0);


    // Now fire a click on the send button
    sendMessageButton.performAction (AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

XML config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged"
  android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
  android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
  android:notificationTimeout="100"
  android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
</accessibility-service>
```

I removed this

```
android:packageNames="com.diaryapp"
```

because I want the service to be active in other apps and be able to perform the click event from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible by design. The Accessibility API is intended to help people with disabilities interact with the UI shown on the phone.